# PHP: Problems Instantiating Class

Tags: php, class, oop, methods, constructor

I try to create new object of a class called Isolate (this class is used to prevent XSS and other attacks via htmlspecialchars and so on).

So, I do it like this:

```
$data['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$data = $isolate->isolateArr($data);
```

And my Isolate class look like this:

```
class Isolate {
    public function isolate($var) {
        $iVar = htmlspecialchars($var);
        $iVar = mysql_real_escape_string($iVar);
        $iVar = stripcslashes($iVar);

        return $iVar;
    }

    public function isolateArr($arr) {
        foreach($arr as &$instance) {
            $instance = $this->isolate($instance);
        }
        unset($instance);
        return $arr;
    }
```

But as the result I have a warning like `Missing argument 1 for Isolate`. As I understand, it asks me for the argument for the first function, but I do not need to call the first one, I need to call the second (because I have an array in this case).

So, why does it always ask for the first function argument? There in no any `__construct` method, what is the point?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`isolate()` is your constructor method.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

> For backwards compatibility, if PHP 5 cannot find a __construct() function for a given class, and the class did not inherit one from a parent class, it will search for the old-style constructor function, by the name of the class.

Comment: Should adding the `__construct() { $a = 'b'; }` help?

Comment: I have no idea what $a ='b'; is supposed to do, but whatever.

Comment: I mean something abstract. As I am not sure I am allowed to create abstract constructor method

Comment: Seems like it would be easier to rename your errant function than create an empty useless constructor you don't need.

Comment: Logically, but it does not solve my problem. It will ask for the missing argument. And since I have two different methods for sanitizing single vars and arrays, it still give me the error that `argument 1 expects to be string, array given`.
As I can remember, `__construct`or method will always be called once instantiating a class

Comment: If you rename `isolate` then you will no longer have a constructor method.

Comment: *headdesk*

If you renamed it, why would it be the constructor anymore? Did you read the quote I posted? Why on earth would it still be the constructor if you called it `foo` instead of `isolate`? Think about it. And don't reply until you actually TRY WHAT I SUGGESTED.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not understood it correctly from the beginning. Sorry